# Splitting a beamer animation

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays

I have a complex animation that evolves over a series of slides (a `\foreach \frm in {1,...,12}\only<\frm>{` loop where certain parts are selected on individual slides with `\visible`).

So far I had all overlays inside a single frame, but I would like to distribute it to several frames so I can put other frames (with text and other things) in between, so I moved the entire `tikzpicture` where all overlays are created into a `\newcommand{\makeAnimation}[1]` such that I can say, e.g.

```
\begin{frame}{First part of the animation}
  \makeAnimation{1,...,4}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Some explanations}
  Lorem ipsum
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Next part}
  \makeAnimation{4,...,7}
\end{frame}
```

(It is easier to create the whole thing in one go, because I would have to copy a lot of code otherwise)

However, the after the portion of the animation that is (correctly) generated by `\makeAnimation{1,...,4}` I get an extra empty slide, which I am unable to move away. Worse, if I change the `\only` after the `\foreach` statement, into a `\visible` (this keeps the centered tikzpicture from jumping around) it generates all slides from 1 ... 12 but leaves 5 ... 12 blank.

How can I fix this and get rid of the extra slides? At this point I would accept any hack as long as I don't have to split up/redo the animation.

---

Small example:

```
\documentclass[
  presentation,
  english,
]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\makeAnimation}[1]{
  \begin{center}
  \scalebox{0.7} {
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \frm in {#1} {
      \only<\frm>{
        \node {FRAME \frm};
        \visible<3>{\node at (4,0) {three hippos};}
        \visible<4-5>{\node (a) at (2,0) {a couple giraffes};}
        \visible<5-6>{\node (b) at (4,2) {hello};}
        \visible<5>{\path[-] (a) edge (b);}
        \visible<6>{\node at (4,0) {six elephants};}
      }   
    }   
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{foo}
  \makeAnimation{1,...,4}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{bar}
  next slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Produces

```
foo FRAME 1
foo FRAME 2
foo FRAME 3 three hippos
foo FRAME 4 a couple giraffes
foo                  % evil blank slide
bar next slide
```

Comment: I think this would be a lot easier to diagnose if you added a minimal working example. You have some code now, but I would be interested in the definition of `\makeanimation` for instance. Best would be to just add a complete minimal working example showing the problem.

Comment: @RoelofSpijker: I added a small (close to minimal) example to demonstrate the issue. Note that changing `only` to `visible` will produce two blank slides.

Comment: I have changed the title from "Overlays generate empty slide at the end" to "Splitting a beamer animation", since I think that's the larger question you were asking and, perhaps, it will now be easier to find in a search.

Comment: @RyanReich: +1 on that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I may be so bold, I want to say that you are doing it wrong.  `beamer` has a built-in way of "cutting" frames: the `\againframe` command, combined with overlay specifications on the frame to be cut.  It's described in the manual, section 11.2 ("Repeating a frame at a later point"), and works like this:

```
\documentclass[
  presentation,
  english,
]{beamer}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}<1-4>[label = foo]{foo}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \onslide<1>
  \node {Frame 1};
 \onslide<2>
  \node {Frame 2};
 \onslide<3>
  \node at (4,0) {three hippos};
 \onslide<4-5>
  \node (a) at (2,0) {a couple giraffes};
 \onslide<5-6>
  \node (b) at (4,2) {hello};
 \onslide<5>
  \path[-] (a) edge (b);
 \onslide<6>
  \node at (4,0) {six elephants};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{bar}
  next slide
\end{frame}

\againframe<4-6>{foo}
\end{document}
```

Basically, the first frame is the "template" for the animation and replaces your `\makeAnimation`.  The overlay specification says only to run it for four slides, and then cut to the explanation.  Then `\againframe` comes in and produces slides 4 through 7 to finish the animation.

I am a little annoyed that it is necessary to write `Frame 1` and `Frame 2` separately, as there does exist a counter `framenumber` that should print the correct value in a single `\theframenumber` command.  However, when I tried

```
\onslide<1-2>
 \node {Frame \theframenumber};
```

it just printed "Frame 1" twice.  Using `\only<1-2>` did the same, and in fact, using `Frame \theframenumber` with two `\onslide` commands also printed "Frame 1" even after `\onslide<2>`!  Perhaps this is a bug; certainly, this counter is not mentioned in the manual, so perhaps it is not supported.

Comment: I ... don't have words. This is *exactly* what I wanted to have. I've been messing around with increasingly ugly (seriously, you wouldn't believe it) hacks to get this right. Just wow! **Thank you!**

Answer (score 1):

Avoid unnecessary `\visible<...>` lines, let it depend on your argument range. After I removed the `\visible<5>` and `\visible<6>` lines in your example, the empty frame was gone.

The code (before the question has been updated) could even be reduced, doing the same but no empty slide:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \frm in {#1} {
  \only<\frm>{
    \node {FRAME \frm};
    \visible<\frm>{\node at (4,0) {its \frm};}
  }   
}   
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Even with the update, you could use `\if` or similar or a `\foreach` loop for `\visible` and a variable for the node content.

If it's just for preventing jumping, I would use `\overlayarea`.

Comment: Sure, but that completely misses the point of the complete animation.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not. Perhaps the example was a bit too simple, but in general there are interleaving visibility scopes where the content is not derived that easily from the value of `\frm`. Let me update the question.

Comment: I tried wrapping `\visible` in an `\ifthenelse` statement. But with the exact same effect. I didn't manage to get it working with `\if`.

Answer (score 1):

I found that it is best to play dirty with tex. This does the trick, as it wraps the entire thing.

```
% parameter documentation
%  #1: current frame
%  #2: displayed range minimum
%  #3: displayed range maximum
%  #4: object range minimum
%  #5: object range maximum
%  #6: object
\newcommand{\showPart}[6]{\ifnum#1<#4\relax\else\ifnum#5<#1\relax\else\visible<\ifnum#2<#4 #4\else#2\fi-\ifnum#3<#5 #3\else#5\fi>{#6}\fi\fi}
```

Which allows the animation command to look like that:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \frm in {#1,...,#2} {
      %\only<\frm>{  %%%%% IMPORTANT: remove this!
        \node at (-4,\frm) {FRAME \frm}; %% all four shown all the time!
        \showPart{\frm}{#1}{#2}{2}{4}{\node at (4,0) {it's 2-4};}
        \showPart{\frm}{#1}{#2}{4}{5}{\node at (4,2) {it's 4-5};}
        \showPart{\frm}{#1}{#2}{5}{5}{\node at (4,4) {it's 5};}
      %}
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: On the contrary, I have found that it is best to be stodgily bureaucratic with *La*TeX and to do it "by the book" whenever possible.  A package like `beamer`, which has quite a large book indeed, should be expected to anticipate this kind of need.